# Multi-Condition Query

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

My companies resident pl/sql guru is out on vacation this week and I thought I would try the gurus here with my question. I like to think my SQL is of a medium level, but, I am new Oracle.

I have a table that has 3 columns : Id[Numeric(9,2)], FirstName[VarChar2(20)], LastName[VarChar2(25)]

I am trying to write 1 sql query that can support and return the following :

1. If FirstName, LastName & Id match = 'Enrolled'
2. If Id missing or not matched = 'Not Enrolled'
3. If Id & LastName match, but FirstName doesn't = 'FirstName Does Not Match'
4. If Id & FirstName match, but LastName doesn't = 'LastName Does Not Match'
5. If ID matches, but the FirstName & LastName doesn't = 'FirstName & LastName Does Not Match'

I can do this over multiple queries, but what fun is that. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use union to return a single resultset

or

use a function to return a string if a given condition is met:

StringIf(condition, valueToReturnIfTrue, valueToReturnIfFalse)

and use it in the select:

SELECT StringIf(t.fname = t.lname, 'true', 'false') as samenames, StringIf(..) as same2,

Please mark if you like it :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have another table `cmpTable ( cmpId, cmpFirstName, cmpLastName )` with equivalent column definitions and cmpID the PK to store the set of candidates,

```
  select cmpId
         CASE 4 * eqID + 2 * eqFN + eqLN
             WHEN 7 THEN 'Enrolled'
             WHEN 5 THEN 'FirstName Does Not Match'
             WHEN 6 THEN 'LastName Does Not Match'
             WHEN 4 THEN 'FirstName & LastName Does Not Match'
             ELSE 'Not Enrolled'
         END
    from (
              select cmpId
                   , CASE ID        WHEN cmpID          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END    eqID
                   , CASE FirstName WHEN cmpFirstName   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END    eqFN
                   , CASE LastName  WHEN cmpLastName    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END    eqLN
                from table      t1
                join cmpTable   ct ON ( ct.cmpID = t1.ID )
               union
              select cmpId
                   , 0      eqID
                   , 0      eqFN
                   , 0      eqLN
                from cmpTable
               where not exists (
                        select 1 
                          from table t2
                         where t2.ID = cmpID
                     )
         ) 
       ;
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses. I decided to go the UNION route... it was easiest.